# How would I turn a pandas column into a list depending on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say I have a table like this and store it to my df:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
| Block | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
|     1 | A    |    1 | 1F   |
|     1 | B    |    2 | 3D   |
|     1 |      |    3 |      |
|     2 | C    |    2 |      |
|     2 | G    |      |      |
|     3 | H    |    5 | 1D   |
|     3 | I    |    2 | 3H   |
|     3 |      |      | 4K   |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

How would I use the method

```
df['col1'].tolist()
```

but only when block column is 1. Ik I could loop through it, but I've read that iterating over a pandas df isn't the best thing to do, and wanted to know if there is a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to list, if u want to do any operation on the column why not do it on dataframe itself.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Block'].eq(1),'col1'].tolist()`? -->`['A', 'B', '']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: There are two questions I thought you might be asking, so I answered both. I'm going to clean up this answer in a minute.

If you just want a list containing the elements of col1 for which the same row has 'Block' == 1;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Block': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'col1':['A', 'B', '', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'I', '']})

ones_part = df['Block'] == 1

df[ones_part]['col1'].tolist()
```

If you want to **transform** the entries of col1 when 'Block' == 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Block': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'col1':['A', 'B', '', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'I', '']})

df['col1'].where(df['Block'] != 1, other=df['col1'].apply(list))
```

Also, just for clarity- there are a couple of reasons not to iterate over dataframes. One is because certain operations are much much faster using native pandas methods; they're implemented in C rather than in python. The other is for clarity's sake- it's considered more readable.

Comment: The first answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!